# Get Last Line Of CSV File In Python Using DictReader

Tags: python

Didn't manage to find any answer for that, I prefer to use DictReader and still be able to reach last line of CSV File efficiently, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

if you keep the values in a list you can try "-1"

```
list[-1]
```

Comment: yeah, but that's not going to be efficient, it will cause me to transform DictReader into list and all I want to do is access the last line, transforming the whole reader into list could be very not efficient for my case (csv file with over 200k rows)

Comment: maybe you should use Async. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate the file... The last line will be in the loop variable:

```py
import csv

with open("test.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in reader:
        pass

print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will do the required thing for you efficiently

```
with open("test.csv", "r") as f:
    last_line = f.readlines()[-1]
    print(last_line)
```